# My back foot keeps slipping in my animation?

Tags: animation, rigging

So I created a walk cycle for my ATST for it to walk up some stairs. I'm almost done with it, but I am having a problem. Whenever the ATST moves up the stairs, the back foot slides a little bit. Like its on ice or something.

To accomplish the ATST to walk up the stairs, I key framed a stationary walk cycle (where it didn't leave the first step). Then I key framed the root bone to move forward so that it would move up the stairs.

Does anyone know how to prevent the back foot from slipping???

Here is a rendered [video](https://1drv.ms/v/s!Ah2aL3r7RO3ThbZH57kOv6diUEYxUw) of my problem. And here is a copy of my [Blender file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah2aL3r7RO3ThbZI_YhBi7TvOzBLEQ).

Answer (score 1):

You need to bring correction to the feet positions. What you can do is:

- Put your 3D view in Right Orthographic. In the *Dopesheet* / *Action Editor* mode, load the walk animation called "stairs". Enable the *Only Include Channels Relating To Selected Object* option so that you'll only see the selected bone keyframes.

[image]

- Look when the first slipping happens, it's between frame 23 and 30.

[image]

- So what you need to do is correct the foot position at frame 30 so that if stays at the same position as frame 23. Delete the current frame 30 keyframe. As your root bone is moving, you can't just copy paste the keyframes of 23, you need to visually position the foot at frame 30 and create new keyframe (<kbd>i</kbd> > *LocRot*). Also make sure that your *Graph Editor* curves are linear and not bezier (press <kbd>T</kbd> > *Linear*) so that it doesn't smooth the movement. Do the same for the next slippings.

[image]

Comment: So basically at frame 30 just move the foot exactly at the same position as frame 23?

Comment: yes, delete the current frame 30 keyframe, position the foot correctly, create new keyframe, and so on

Comment: So after deleting keyframe 30, manually moving the leg to the same location as keyframe 23, and inserting a keyframe, the foot still slips on the y-axis.

Comment: I'm not copying and pasting the keyframes. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: as I say, don't copy paste, at frame 30 just move the foot at the same position as it is at frame 23 and insert keyframe (LocRotScale)

Comment: I’m not copy/pasting the foot. I am physically moving the foot on frame 30. It seems to help a little bit, but it is still slipping on the y-axis.

Comment: please share your current file

Comment: Sure thing! [blend file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah2aL3r7RO3ThbZ6R8c5ioP8xCiX_g)

Comment: the blend: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=Va39MEQJ" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Va39MEQJ/)

Comment: I don't know if you did it but in my opinion you didn't simplify it because you mix walk cycle and complicated armature move ;) actually your problem is that your curves in the Graph Editor are bezier (smoothed), you need to make them linear (press T > Linear) so that it doesn't create smoothed movement, therefore slipping

Comment: What are the more complicated armature movements?

Comment: Maybe what you could have done is one walk cycle then copy paste and move the whole thing wih the root bone within 2 frames (so no root sliding)?

Comment: what I mean: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=nl6BvgxZ" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/nl6BvgxZ/)